# Pushing to array of for-in loop to extend the number of iterations of that for-in loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-in-loop

Consider this in Javascript:

```
var words = ['hello,','how','are'];
for(var word in words) {
    console.log(words[word]);
    if (words[word] == 'are') {
        words.push('you');
    }
}
```

It outputs:

```
hello,
how
are
```

My expectation is that it would output this to the console:

```
hello,
how
are
you
```

So, it appears that the number of iterations is set by the length of words at the start of the loop, and it cannot update that number as the length of words changes through the duration of the loop. Can anyone think of another way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `for..in` to iterate over an array. Use the new `for..of` if it's available or keep track of an index to iterate. Both will iterate *online* (i.e. over items that are added). `.forEach` does not iterate online.

```
var words = ['hello,','how','are'];
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    console.log(words[i]);
    if (words[i] == 'are') {
        words.push('you');
    }
}

// ES6
let words = ['hello,','how','are'];
for (let word of words) {
    console.log(word);
    if (word == 'are') {
        words.push('you');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop and increment/decrement your own count.

Note that it is considered bad practice to change the content of the array/object you are iterating over inside the loop, precisely because it leads to unexpected behaviours.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a new array:

```
var words = ['hello,','how','are'];
var newwords = [];
for(var word in words) {
    console.log(words[word]);
    newwords.push(words[word]);
    if (words[word] == 'are') {
        newwords.push('you');
    }
}
console.log(newwords); //["hello,", "how", "are", "you"]
```

But I'm not certain why your code doesn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/n0m27reo/

However, I'm partial to using `for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)`, which I think is also more efficient.  It also allows what you're trying to accomplish without the need for a second array:

http://jsfiddle.net/n0m27reo/1/

```
var words = ['hello,','how','are'];
for(var i=0; i < words.length; i++) {
    console.log(words[i]);
    if (words[i] == 'are') {
        words.push('you');
    }
}
console.log(words); //["hello,", "how", "are", "you"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `for` loop that check the `length` in every iteration instead of the `for in` :

```
var words = ['hello,','how','are'];
for(var i=0; i < words.length; i++) {
    console.log(words[i]);
    if (words[i] == 'are') {
        words.push('you');
    }
}
```

Output :

```
hello,
how
are
you
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The old-fashioned way will do what you want:

```
var words = ['hello,','how','are'];
var newwords = [];
for(var word=0; word < words.length; word++) {
    console.log(words[word]);
    if (words[word] == 'are') {
        words.push('you');
    }
}
```